# ionic build android error (:transformClassesWithDexForDebug)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Everything was fine and working perfectly till i execute the command "ionic build android"
and then this error occurs.

:transformClassesWithDexForDebugjava.lang.UnsupportedClassesVersionError: com.android.dx/command/Main : Unsupported Major.minor version 52.0

and so on......

[image]

Comment: Its a Java error. JDK was outdated. Updating JDK and JRE resolved my issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you have an old version of Java. Update your JDK to Version 8.

You can download it : [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Also don't forget to set your JAVA_HOME variable to new version (via Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables) and then restart. Make sure that when you build your project, it will indicate that you're using JDK version 8.

You might have gradle problem. To fix it, do the following:

```
npm install -g gradle
ionic platform rm android
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
```

Comment: I Already fixed it. 
My Java was Outdated (Did same as you Described).
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I had exact same error yesterday :) Glad that you've figured it out quickly!